# How to calculate number of used columns per row in excel 2007 vba

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I want to calculate number of used columns for each row in excel 2007 using VBA.
I am calculating number of used rows by using ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
and now I want that, i just pass cells(1,1).value to a function that give me total number of used column for that specific row.

Thanks

Comment: How do you define "number of used columns"? For example, if only cells C1 and G1 have content, do you then want row 1 to have 2, 5, or 7 "used columns"? Please clarify, and preferably show us an example.

Comment: Concur completely with Jean-Francois. This question needs further detail and explanation

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Below example for column A:

```
WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count ))
```

Comment: -1. Even though the question is unclear `SUM` has no place in the answer.

Comment: HI brettdj, Simply I want to get number of used column for eachrow in excel. For this purpose I need to use VBA fucntion.